# Xorg on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS crashes frequently when playing videos

Tags: xorg, laptop, intel-graphics

**Background:**
I have been using Ubuntu on a desktop for 2 years now and it worked well. I thought I'd try running it on my Dell Inspiron 7373 laptop.

**Problem:**
Xorg crashes a lot when I try to play a video (almost 100%), be it web streaming or local file, most of the time right after going into full screen mode.

**Setup:**

- Intel® UHD Graphics 620
- Dual monitors

**Driver** (`lshw -c video`):

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:125 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**`.crash` log file:** 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OY04fg0ubIrK0gMdiI70Yh-M0BCDQCBU

**Xorg log:** 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z_x_ZENUuFHxjbKKxtpn-wsUI5EGw15y

**Memory** (`free;swapon`):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16159572     2052092    12783380      191092     1324100    13624140
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G   0B   -2
```

**What I have tried:**

1) configure `20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"
 Identifier "Card0"
 Driver "Intel"
 Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

2) `sudo apt update` & `upgrade`

3) Disable/enable hardware acceleration in Chrome

If there are any other logs that will help, please let me know
Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1042479/edit ) your post and add  the `free;swapon` results.

Comment: @waltinator thanks. i have added the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best fix but hope it helps someone.

The crashes stopped coming after I made these 2 changes:

1. uninstall easystroke
2. change `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` to

   ```
   Section "Device"
     Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
     Driver "Intel"
     Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
   EndSection
   ```